# Gemetric representation of complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

Find the geometric representation of;

### |z-2| - |z+2| < 2

things i know;

| z - 2 | is the distance between a point z and the point (2,0) in the complex plane. It suppose to represent a hyperbola, BUT i have no idea on how to get there. i know the standard form of a hyperbola, but just, no idea on how to manipulate this expression into the standard form.

Comment: The locus $|z-2|-|z+2|=2$ is a hyperbola. The region of your problem is *related* to that hyperbola. What are you asking for? The Cartesian equation of the hyperbola? This can be looked up. Or do you want a calculation from the expression $|z-2|-|z+2|=1$?

Comment: i know the Cartesian equation of the hyperbola. The answer is in set notation. There have been questions before this,. relating to circles,as you can imagine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to manipulate it algebraically (without considering the geometric definition of the hyperbola), then let $$z=x+iy$$ and note that $$|z|^2=z\overline{z}=x^2+y^2.$$

**Edit**

First, as someone mentioned in the comments, I am not sure if you want the equation of the hyperbola or the set of points that satisfy your relation. This is how you can algebraically obtain the equation of the hyperbola:

Consider $|z-2|-|z+2|= 2$
Then, letting $z=x+iy$ and using the definition of $|z|$ above, we have
\begin{align*}
|(x-2)+iy|-|(x+2)+iy|&=2 \\
\sqrt{(x-2)^2+y^2}-\sqrt{(x+2)^2+y^2}&=2 \\
(x-2)^2+y^2&=\left(2+\sqrt{(x+2)^2+y^2}\right)^2 \\
&=4+4\sqrt{(x+2)^2+y^2}+(x+2)^2+y^2.
\end{align*}
So
\begin{align*}
\left((x-2)^2-(x+2)^2-4\right)^2&=\left(4\sqrt{(x+2)^2+y^2}\right)^2 \\
\left(-8x-4 \right)^2&=16\left((x+2)^2+y^2\right)\\
16(4x^2+4x+1)&=16\left((x+2)^2+y^2\right) \\
4x^2+4x+1-(x+2)^2-y^2&=0 \\
3x^2-3-y^2&=0 \\
\end{align*}

So the equation of the hyperbola is 
$$x^2-\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^2=1$$

The geometric way is perhaps simpler:
The equation of the hyperbola is given as
$$|z-z_1|-|z-z_2|=2a,$$ where $z_1,z_2$ are the foci (remember $z=x+iy$ so we can assign the coordinates $(x,y)$ to $z$), and $a$ is half of the major axis. For our example we have $z_1=(2,0)$ and $z_2=(-2,0)$ and the focal length is $2$. Since the focal length is given by $\sqrt{a^2+b^2},$ where b is the minor axis, we have 
$$2^2=1+b^2,$$ so $b= \sqrt{3}$. Putting all of this together gives the same equation as above.

**Note**
Technically we want $$||z-z_1|-|z-z_2||=2a,$$ in order to ensure that the distance does not become negative  (if we go to the other branch).

**Edit**

To solve your inequality, we do
\begin{align*}
x^2-\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^2&<1 \\
y^2&>3(x^2-1),
\end{align*}
So
$$y>\sqrt{3(x^2-1)}$$ or
$$y<-\sqrt{3(x^2-1)}$$

Comment: are you suggesting that i square both sides of the expression?

Comment: Not exactly. Personally I would use the geometric idea of the hyperbola to come up with the equation in Cartesian coordinates. However, if you insist on doing algebra, you will have to use the relations I provided...I will edit my answer with some work.

Comment: wow, thanks so much!. only question being how would i answer |z-2| - |z+2| < 2. i don't know why i am finding this so difficult :(. The solution you have given me is so enlightening!

Comment: If you like it, perhaps accept it as an answer by clicking the check mark? :)

Comment: I'll answer your question in an edit